# Scripting more hair keys than six

Tags: python, scripting, particles, hair

I need to write a script that allows me to bend a hair to exact coordinates. I've been using -

```
bpy.context.object.particle_systems[0].particles[0].hair_keys[0].co = (x,y,z)
```

but particles[0] seems to only allow 0-5 hair_keys.

Is there anyway to script an increase in the number of hair_keys? Any sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the "segment" to get a higher number of "hair_keys".

[image: Hair Segment Input Field]

In script, you can use bpy.data.particles["ParticleSettings"].hair_step = n,
where n is the segment number, which is len(hair_keys) - 1